# jQuery animate несколько параметров

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Почему не работает полноценно данная строчка кода?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".run").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({ opacity:"0.1", left:"+=400" }, 1200)
        return false;
    });
});
```

Прозрачность именяется, но объект не двигается?

---

slackware 14
firefox 15.0.1

Comment: у меня все работает. и прозрачность и движение. Ищите другие ошибки

Comment: работает ведь [пруф.](http://jsbin.com/onamiq/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

А у вас задано начальное значение left? Попробуйте для #box дописать left: 0;